# How to insert leading zeros on all *.txt files in a directory to get all files with same file name length?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to step through a folder with a batch file. The folder has file names as

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- 10.txt
- 100.txt
- etc.

So I want to rename them to something like

- 001.txt
- 002.txt
- 010.txt
- 100.txt
- etc.

I have tried

```
FOR /R C:\Test\ %%G IN (*.txt) DO echo "%%G"
```

But this gives me an output of

```
1.txt
10.txt
100.txt
2.txt
```

How do I get it to output in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a commented batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem The environment variable LeadingZeros will be a string containing as
rem much zeros as longest file name has characters without file extension.

set "LeadingZeros="

rem The environment variable ZerosCount will have the number of zeros.

set "ZerosCount=0"

rem Search in current directory for files with extension TXT and call for
rem each file name without file extension the subroutine GetLeadingZeros.

for %%I in (*.txt) do call :GetLeadingZeros "%%~nI"

rem Is there no file with more than 1 character, there
rem is nothing to do and therefore exit this batch file.

if %ZerosCount% LEQ 1 endlocal & goto :EOF

rem Otherwise insert at beginning of each file name the string with
rem the leading zeros and rename the file with using only the last
rem ZerosCount characters from file name with leading zeros.

for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    set "FileName=%LeadingZeros%%%~nI"
    ren "%%~fI" "!FileName:~-%ZerosCount%!%%~xI"
)

rem Exit the batch file after renaming all files.

endlocal
goto :EOF

rem This subroutine determines length of current file name and at
rem the same time builds a string with just zeros of same length.

rem Once the file name length and number of zeros for this file is
rem determined, this number is compared with the greatest length already
rem determined before. If this file has a longer file name than all other
rem files before, this file name specifies the number of zeros to insert
rem at begin of each file name in the second loop above.

:GetLeadingZeros
set "TempZeros="
set "TempCount=0"
set "FileName=%~1"

:NextChar
if "%FileName%" == "" goto CompareLengths
set "TempZeros=%TempZeros%0"
set "FileName=%FileName:~1%"
set /A TempCount+=1
goto NextChar

:CompareLengths
if %TempCount% LEQ %ZerosCount% goto :EOF
set "LeadingZeros=%TempZeros%"
set "ZerosCount=%TempCount%"
goto :EOF
```

It is more complex than really necessary if number of digits is fixed. But coding a batch file for a fixed number of digits of 3 was not really interesting for me as being too simple, look this **FOR** loop.

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    set "FileName=00%%~nI"
    ren "%%~fI" "!FileName:~-3!%%~xI"
)
```

The first batch code finds out longest file name in current directory and determines based on this file name the number of leading zeros to insert at beginning of each file name to get finally all files with same file name length.

**EDIT:** This batch code is a bit faster than first one, but does the same:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem The environment variable ZerosCount will have the number of zeros
rem which is equal the number of characters of longest file name.

set "ZerosCount=0"

rem Search in current directory for files with extension TXT and call for
rem each file name without file extension the subroutine GetLeadingZeros.

for %%I in (*.txt) do call :GetLeadingZeros "%%~nI"

rem Is there no file with more than 1 character, there
rem is nothing to do and therefore exit this batch file.

if %ZerosCount% LEQ 1 endlocal & goto :EOF

rem The environment variable LeadingZeros will be a string containing as
rem much zeros as longest file name has characters without file extension.

set "LeadingZeros="
for /L %%N in (1,1,%ZerosCount%) do set "LeadingZeros=!LeadingZeros!0"

rem Otherwise insert at beginning of each file name the string with
rem the leading zeros and rename the file with using only the last
rem ZerosCount characters from file name with leading zeros.

for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    set "FileName=%LeadingZeros%%%~nI"
    echo ren "%%~fI" "!FileName:~-%ZerosCount%!%%~xI"
)

rem Exit the batch file after renaming all files.

endlocal
goto :EOF

rem This subroutine determines length of current file name.

rem Once the file name length is determined, this number is compared with the
rem greatest length already determined before. If this file has a longer file
rem name than all other files before, this file name specifies the number of
rem zeros to insert at begin of each file name in the third loop above.

:GetLeadingZeros
set "NameLength=0"
set "FileName=%~1"

:NextChar
if "%FileName%" == "" goto CompareLengths
set "FileName=%FileName:~1%"
set /A NameLength+=1
goto NextChar

:CompareLengths
if %NameLength% LEQ %ZerosCount% goto :EOF
set "ZerosCount=%NameLength%"
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

PS: I have never written for myself a batch file for renaming files as I use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) with its built-in [multi-rename tool](http://www.ghisler.com/advanced.htm#tutorial_rename) making file/folder renames always a very simple task with no need of coding skills.

Answer (score 0):

A robust solution should have the following features:

- Only .txt files with a base name that is purely numeric should be renamed
- If the base name length already exceeds your desired width, then it should be ignored (not truncated)

The following solutions meet the above criteria. I chose to pad to 3 digits. It should be a straight forward exercise to expand the width

**Pure Batch**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.txt^|findstr /i "^[0-9][0-9]*\.txt$"'
) do (
  set "old=%%F"
  set "new=00%%F"
  if !old!==!old:~-6! echo ren !old! !new:~-7!
)
```

**JREN.BAT - Hybrid JScript/batch renaming utility**

[JREREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) is a generic regular expression renaming utility. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is available by running `jren /?`, or `jren /??` if you want paged help.

```
jren "^\d+\.txt$" "lpad($0,'0000000')" /i /j
```

Remember that JREN is a batch script, so you must use `call jren` if you put the command within another batch script.